# Why is {{ list.title }} not showing

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I am following a tutorial on youtube to build my first MEAN stack app, and the title of the list is not showing. I am using Insomnia to make the lists.
Here is my code in the backend for Node and express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('./database/mongoose');

const List = require('./database/models/list');
const Task = require('./database/models/task');
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
})




app.get('/lists', (req, res) => {
  List.find({})
  .then(lists => res.send(lists))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});

app.post('/lists', (req, res)=>{
 ( new List({ 'title': req.body.title }))
   .save()
   .then((list) => res.send(list))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});

app.get('/lists/:listId', (req,res) => {
  List.find({ _id:req.params.listId})
  .then((list) => res.send(list))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});

app.patch('/lists/:listId', (req,res) => {
  List.findOneAndUpdate({ '_id': req.params.listId}, {$set:req.body})
  .then((list) => res.send(list))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
})

app.delete('/lists/:listId', (req,res) => {
  const deleteTasks = (list)=> {
    Task.deleteMany({ _listId:list._id})
    .then(() => list)
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  };
  List.findByIdAndDelete({ _id: req.params.listId})
               .then((list) => res.send(deleteTasks(list)))
              .catch((error) => console.log(error));

})
/* Tasks*/

app.get('/lists/:listId/tasks', (req,res) => {
  Task.find({ _listId: req.params.listId})
  .then((tasks) => res.send(tasks))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});

app.post('/lists/:listId/tasks', (req, res)=>{
  ( new Task({ '_listId': req.params.listId , 'title': req.body.title}))
    .save()
    .then((tasks) => res.send(tasks))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
 });

 app.get('/lists/:listId/tasks/:taskId', (req,res) => {
  Task.findOne({ _listId: req.params.listId, _id:req.params.taskId})
  .then((task) => res.send(task))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
});

app.patch('/lists/:listId/tasks/:taskId', (req,res) => {
  Task.findOneAndUpdate({ _listId: req.params.listId, _id:req.params.taskId}, {$set:req.body})
  .then((task) => res.send(task))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
})

app.delete('/lists/:listId/tasks/:taskId', (req,res) => {
  Task.findByIdAndDelete({ _listId: req.params.listId, _id:req.params.taskId})
  .then((task) => res.send(task))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error));
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server Connected on Port 3000"));
```

The angular service files are:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{ WebService} from './web.service';
import Task from './models/task';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {

  constructor(private webService: WebService) { }

  getLists(){
    return this.webService.get('lists');
  }
  createLists(title:string){
  return this.webService.post('lists', {title})
  }
  getTasks(listId: string){
    return this.webService.get('lists/${listId}/tasks');
  }
  createTasks(listId: string, title:string){
  return this.webService.post('lists/${listId}/tasks', {title})
  }
  deleteLists(listId: string){
    return this.webService.delete('lists/${listId}')
  }
  deleteTasks(listId: string){
    return this.webService.delete('lists/${listId}/tasks/${taskId}')
  }
  setCompleted(listId: string, task: Task){
    return this.webService.patch('lists/${listId}/tasks/${task._id}', {completed: !task.completed})
  }
}
```

and

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import{HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebService {
readonly ROOT_URL;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.ROOT_URL = "http//localhost:3000";
   }

   get(uri: string){
     return this.http.get('${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}');
   }

   post(uri: string, payload: Object){
    return this.http.post('${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}', payload);
  }

  patch(uri: string, payload: Object){
    return this.http.patch('${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}', payload);
  }

  delete(uri: string){
    return this.http.delete('${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}');
  }

}
```

and Finally the HTML file is

```
<div class= "centered-content">
  <div class= "task-manager-container">
    <div class= "sidebar">
      <h1 class= "title has-text-primary">Lists
      </h1>
      <div class= "list-menu">
       <a href="#" class="list-menu-item " *ngFor="let list of lists">
         <p class="white-text">
          {{ list.title }}
           <span class="pull-right task-delete btn-rounded-corners">X</span>
         </p>
       </a>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded-corners">Add Lists</button>
    </div>
  <div class="task-list-container">
    <h1 class= "title has-text-primary">Tasks</h1>
    <div class="task complete">
      <p class="white-text">
        Task
        <span class="pull-right task-delete btn-rounded-corners">X</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the task-view.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import List from 'src/app/models/list';
import Task from 'src/app/models/task';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-view.component.scss']
})
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {
  lists: List[]= [];
  task: Task[]= [];
  constructor(private taskService: TaskService) { }

  ngOnInit()  {
    this.taskService.getLists().subscribe((lists: List[]) => this.lists = lists);
  }

}
```

It might be a deprecated syntax or a missing part in the API.

Comment: Can you please attach the component's '.ts' file in your question?

Comment: have you checked browser network tab? make sure you are getting the response

Comment: @snsakib I got you

Comment: @Tony What is the browser network tab?

Comment: @CJOSEPH Can you try adding the output you get after the request is made on the angular component.ts file. Please console.log the response. It won't make sense if the data is not being returned at all in the first place. Second of all do try to assign your variable an interface that matches with the response.

Comment: open DevTools (ctrl+shift+i chrome), goto network tab and press ctrl+r and see request

Comment: @Tony You're a g, the issue was that I put "http//localhost:3000" instead of "http://localhost:3000".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `TaskService` & `WebService` files you've used single-quote(').
Replace it with back-ticks (`).

I'm giving an example below:

you've used:

```
this.http.get('${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}')
```

It should be:

```
this.http.get(`${this.ROOT_URL}/${uri}`)
```

[Learn more about Template literals here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Ok thank you so much, this is one answer, but I found another issue that was in the web.service.ts folder. It was "http://localhost:3000" not "http//localhost:3000".